# I need to download and open an email attachment but how to check if it's safe before?

Tags: linux, email-attachments

Someone sent a 39 kb file email attachment.
A strange picture appears over the attachment. I didn't open it.

I would need to check the file but I'm afraid it's a scam.
I was planning to log into my email account from a Linux live distro (like LPS, delivered for security purposes, which does not allow to explore files from the media installed in the hdd or ssd) and open the file from there, so if it's a virus it will not attack my system I think...Is it still safe? Or should I avoid opening it at all?

- How may I **check** if a **file** **attached** to an email message contains
  viruses/malwares/(...) without risks?

Comment: The usual way is to upload it to an online virus checker like Virustotal, and/or right-click and chose "scan" from your anti-virus.

Comment: I removed the story fragment because it was not enough to help with the question and was very confusing.

Comment: If someone I don’t know sends me an attachment I don’t expect, I’m throwing it away.  Too many scams and too many attachment-related vulnerabilities.  I’d hate to work in a corporate account-receivables office: probably under constant “invoice attachment” attack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An online virus checker would be good. Some e-mail clients such as gmail automatically scan attachments for viruses. Alternatively, you could download, but not open the attachment and scan with a program like Avast! or some similar antivirus.

However, those scans can't possibly cover every single type of malware.

I would say, if you are expecting or have reason to suspect an attack from the attachment, either don't open it all or go with your Live Linux Distro Option if you must.